# Error showing while creating the database structure on Redmine

Tags: ruby

I am now setting up my Redmine 2.1.0 in Debian. When I ran this `RAILS_ENV=production rake db:migrate` in Redmine directory. It's showing an error like this

```
rake aborted!
Invalid preference factor: 3.0

Tasks: TOP => db:migrate => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

My Ruby version is 1.8.7

When I gave this command "ruby -e 'p 0.3". it prints 3.0. I don't know what the issue was. How can I set up Redmine 2.1.0 in my organization?

Answer (score 0):

Seems you have an issue with your specific ruby.

[rvm](http://rvm.io) is your friend. Try installing 1.9.3-head, create gemset for redmine and proceed installation.

Big advantage of RVM approach is a fact that new rubies install does not affect system ruby no applications using it.